# Get Executable Path of Window by Handle - Access Denied

Tags: c#, filepath, handle

I am trying to get Executable Path of Window by Handle.
I am using the following code to achieve:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out uint processId);

public string GetFilePath(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    try
    {
        uint pid = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)pid); //Gets the process by ID.
        return proc.MainModule.FileName.ToString();   //Returns the path.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

and it works fine, except for some applications (such as TeamSpeak 3 64bit [if it matters]).

How can I overcome the Access Denied problem programmaticly?

I tried to use the following aswell but same problem:
[Get a executable path from a window handle?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3d93c3fb-9882-4924-9b19-06c3de11a63b/get-a-executable-path-from-a-window-handle?forum=windowssecurity)
[Access denied while getting process path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399819/access-denied-while-getting-process-path)
[How to Get Elevated Process Path in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304668/How-to-Get-Elevated-Process-Path-in-Net)

Comment: Start by changing a setting so your program runs as a 64-bit process.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = AnyCPU (untick Prefer 32-bit if you see it).  A process otherwise can prevent you from messing with it so this is no slamdunk.

Comment: @HansPassant Platform target was on AnyCPU (its the default). I tried all the options (x86, x64, AnyCPU) but I still get the same Access Denied on some apps. Anyway I cant see how changing the Plaform target should solve it

Comment: You are running elevated? And in the same session as the target process?

Comment: Ok, Apperantly the elevated did work. I used the wrong ProcessAccessFlags and thats why it didnt work.

Comment: @Ron I am facing same issue . Could you please explain in details what was the fix of this?