# CreateProcessAsUser from service with proper PEB and ACL

Tags: windows, winapi

I have read tons of SO questions on this matter, but I didn't find a real definitive guide for doing this the right way.

My goal is to enumerate [disconnected and active] user console sessions and start a process in each one of them. Every user session process requires at least these rights in its DACL :

[Token access rights :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- `TOKEN_QUERY` (for [GetTokenInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- `TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE` (for [GetTokenInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

[Process access rights :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

- `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` (for [OpenProcessToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ` (for [GetModuleFileNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` (used with [GetTokenInformation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get other processes' username later with [LookupAccountSid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

But as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (at the bottom) : `"Windows Vista introduces protected processes to enhance support for Digital Rights Management. The system restricts access to protected processes and the threads of protected processes."`
So I thought maybe only with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` I can get some information about other processes. I tried [QueryFullProcessImageName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for elevated processes starting from Vista (see [Giori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654195/1449056)) but it [doesn't work anymore as it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583644/get-executable-path-of-window-by-handle-access-denied).
**Solution :** CreateProcessAs_*LOCAL_SYSTEM* using a duplicated token of the Windows service.
**Problem :** The spawned processes should have the respective logged on user's environment variables set to be able to locate network printers and mapped drives among other things. But if I use the service's token I inherit its PEB and I can't even translate the mapped drives to their UNC paths.

So I started looking for ways to "elevate" the process and bypassing the UAC prompt, I tried :

- Enabling some privileges like `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` in the token using [AdjustTokenPrivileges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (does not work if the token does not have those privileges, verification can be done first using [LookUpPrivilegeValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
- using the token from `winlogon.exe.` (does not work)
- Changing the DACL ([source code](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderRasch/6135882)) (didn't work)

The steps I'm following are :

1. Enumerate sessions using [WTSEnumerateSessions()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Get the token (two choices) :

   - SYSTEM token : [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)([GetCurrentProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),TokenAccessLevels.MaximumAllowed, out hProcessToken)
   - User token : [WTSQueryUserToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)(sessionId, out hUserToken)
3. Duplicate the token using [DuplicateTokenEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
4. [LookUpPrivilegeValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [AdjustTokenPrivileges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (useless ?)
5. [CreateEnvironmentBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
6. [CreateProccessAsUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), flags : `NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`, Startup info's desktop : `"WinSta0\Default"`
7. Change process DACL (see link above, useless ?)
8. Dispose/Clean : destroy PEB created, close opened handles and free memory.

**My question :** how to grant the process created using [CreateProccessAsUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from a Windows Service running under `LOCAL_SYSTEM` account enough privileges/rights to get information on other processes (from other sessions; of other users and different integrity levels) without losing the user's environment variables ?

Comment: SeDebugPrivilege really should be the only thing you need.  Does WTSQueryUserToken() not return an elevated token?  It's been a while so I don't remember.  If not you should be able to get it via GetTokenInformation() and TokenLinkedToken.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused about a number of things.

> Every user session process requires at least these rights in its DACL

The process DACL controls access to that process, it does not determine what access that process has.  The security token for the process determines access rights.

> Windows Vista introduces protected processes to enhance support for Digital Rights Management.

It seems clear that you haven't gotten far enough to worry about protected processes yet.  Get it to work for ordinary processes first!

> The spawned processes should have the respective logged on user's environment variables set to be able to locate network printers and mapped drives among other things.

Network printers and mapped drives have nothing to do with environment variables.  I think what you're trying to do is to put the new process into the user's logon session, that's what controls network drive mappings and the like.

> how to grant the process created using CreateProccessAsUser() [...] enough privileges/rights to get information on other processes (from other sessions; of other users and different integrity levels) without losing the user's environment variables ?

Don't.  This would violate the integrity of the security model.

Instead, enumerate and query processes from the system service, and pass only whatever information is necessary to the user session processes, using shared memory (look up "file mapping object" in MSDN) or another suitable IPC mechanism.

Comment: you're right. I was wrong about DACLs and "protected processes"/DRM I should I've read more about it first. Now I get it. `I think what you're trying to do is to put the new process into the user's logon session, that's what controls network drive mappings and the like.` Yes that's what I'm doing but a process created in session 1 of user x with a token from a Windows service running in session 0 under SYSTEM account can't access the personal mapped drive of user x ! I've tried WMI. Same for the network printer.

Comment: You're talking about Remote Desktop sessions.  Logon sessions are different again.  For non-admin users, WTSQueryUserToken should give you a security token that is in the right logon session.  For admin users (with UAC enabled) I'm not sure whether it will give you the elevated token or the restricted token - you want the restricted token.  You may need to use GetTokenInformation with the TokenLinkedToken in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has been asked a while ago. Since I happened to have been doing the same, below is the working pseudo-code.

First, how to run a process in a user session from a service:

```
//IMPORTANT: All error checks are omitted for brevity!
//           Each of the lines of code below MUST be 
//           checked for possible errors!!!

//INFO: The following pseudo-code is intended to run 
//      from the Windows local service.

DWORD dwSessionID;  //Session ID to run your user process in

//Get token for the session ID
HANDLE hToken;
WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionID, &hToken);

//Duplicate this token
HANDLE hToken2;
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

PSID gpSidMIL_High = NULL;

if(you_want_to_change_integrity_level_for_user_process)
{
    if(!Windows_XP)
    {
        //For example, create "high" mandaroty integrity level SID
        ::ConvertStringSidToSid(L"S-1-16-12288", &gpSidMIL_High);

        TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL tml = {0};
        tml.Label.Attributes = SE_GROUP_INTEGRITY;
        tml.Label.Sid = gpSidMIL_High;

        SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenIntegrityLevel, &tml, 
            sizeof(TOKEN_MANDATORY_LABEL) + ::GetSidLengthRequired(1));
    }
}

//Copy environment strings
LPVOID pEnvBlock = NULL;
CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnvBlock, hToken2, FALSE);

//Initialize the STARTUPINFO structure.
// Specify that the process runs in the interactive desktop.
STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.lpDesktop = _T("winsta0\\default");

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

//Create non-const buffer
TCHAR pBuffCmdLine[MAX_PATH];
pBuffCmdLine[0] = 0;

//Copy process path & parameters to the non-constant buffer
StringCchCopy(pBuffCmdLine, MAX_PATH, L"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Brand\\process.exe\" -parameter");

//Impersonate the user
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken2);

//Launch the process in the user session.
bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken2,            // client's access token
    L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Brand\\process.exe",              // file to execute
    pBuffCmdLine[0] != 0 ? pBuffCmdLine : NULL,     // command line
    NULL,              // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    NULL,              // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    FALSE,             // handles are not inheritable
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,   // creation flags
    pEnvBlock,         // pointer to new environment block 
    NULL,              // name of current directory 
    &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi                // receives information about new process
);

//Get last error
nOSError = GetLastError();

//Revert to self
RevertToSelf();

//At this point you may want to wait for the user process to start, etc.
//using its handle in `pi.hProcess`
...

//Otherwise, close handles
if(pi.hProcess)
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
if(pi.hThread)
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

//Clean-up
if(pEnvBlock)
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnvBlock);

CloseHandle(hToken2);
CloseHandle(hToken);

if(gpSidMIL_High)
    ::LocalFree(gpSidMIL_High);
```

If you need to run your process in all sessions with a logged in interactive user, you can run the method I gave above for the sessions that you can obtain from the following enumeration:

```
//Enumerate all sessions
WTS_SESSION_INFO* pWSI = NULL;
DWORD nCntWSI = 0;
if(WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, NULL, 1, &pWSI, &nCntWSI))
{
    //Go through all sessions
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < nCntWSI; i++)
    {
        //To select logged in interactive user session,
        //try to get its name. If you get something, then
        //this session has a user logged in to...
        LPTSTR pUserName = NULL;
        DWORD dwcbSzUserName = 0;
        if(WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
            pWSI[i].SessionId, 
            WTSUserName, &pUserName, &dwcbSzUserName) &&
            pUserName &&
            dwcbSzUserName >= sizeof(TCHAR) &&
            pUserName[0] != 0)
        {
            //Use my method above to run your user process
            // in this session.
            DWORD dwSessionID = pWSI[i].SessionId;

        }

        //Free mem                          
        if(pUserName)
            WTSFreeMemory(pUserName);
    }

    //Free mem
    WTSFreeMemory(pWSI);
}
```

Comment: You do not need to impersonate the user before calling `CreateProcessAsUser()` for the same user. That is why `CreateProcessAsUser()` takes a user token in the first place - to avoid needing to impersonate.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmm. But I thought that we went thru this in my previous question and my conclusion was that impersonation was indeed required: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209760/createprocessasuser-fails-with-error-elevation-required-for-a-process-with-uiacc#comment36352182_23209760

Comment: @c00000fd: only if the service doesn't have the execute right to the executable file you're launching, which is unlikely.  On the other hand, the impersonation doesn't do any harm.

Comment: @HarryJohnston hello, did you find solution for this. I’m dealing with same request. Process starts in user context and I can access to user profile as well but process does not have admin rights

Comment: @Cozdemir, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23793926/886887 (Of course, that will only work if the user actually has admin privileges.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes i discovered that in my tests. I can only do it if user has already that priv. and its enabled. otherwise it seems impossible to do. Thank you