# CreateProcessAsUser fails with ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED for a process with UIAccess="true"

Tags: c++, c, winapi, service, uac

I'm trying to use the following code to run a user-mode process from my service application (running as a `local system`.)

The requirement for the user-mode process is to run **without** elevatation, but to have `UIAccess="true"` in its manifest to be able to [display `top-most` windows correctly under Windows 8](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/05/16/windows-8-topmost-vs-topmost/).

So I do this (from my service) to run my user-mode process:

```
//NOTE: Error checking is omitted for readability
//'dwSessionID' = user session ID to run user-mode process in
//'pUserProcPath' = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Company\\Software\\user_process.exe"

HANDLE hToken = NULL;
WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionID, &hToken);

HANDLE hToken2;
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

LPVOID pEnvBlock = NULL;
CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnvBlock, hToken2, FALSE);

STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.lpDesktop = L"winsta0\\default";

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

//ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken2);   //Not necessary as suggested below

PVOID OldRedir;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldRedir);

BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcessAsUser(
    hToken2,           // client's access token
    pUserProcPath,     // file to execute
    NULL,              // command line
    NULL,              // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    NULL,              // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    FALSE,             // handles are not inheritable
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,   // creation flags
    pEnvBlock,         // pointer to new environment block 
    NULL,              // name of current directory 
    &si,               // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi                // receives information about new process
    );

int nOSError = ::GetLastError();

Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldRedir);
//RevertToSelf();       //Not necessary as suggested below

CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnvBlock);
CloseHandle(hToken2);
CloseHandle(hToken);
```

This runs fine, if `UIAccess="false"` in the manifest for the `user_process.exe`.

But if I do the following:

- Enable `UIAccess="true"` for the `user_process.exe`:

[image]

- Sign it with my code-signing certificate and
- Place it in the `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Software"` folder.

What I get is that `CreateProcessAsUser` fails with the error `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED`.

Can someone suggest how to make it work?

PS. I tried adjusting my service's privileges to enable `SE_DEBUG_NAME` and `SE_TCB_NAME`, but neither helped.

PS2. If I simply double-click my `user_process.exe` process compiled with `UIAccess="true"`, code-signed, and placed in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Software` folder, it starts & runs just fine (not elevated.).

Comment: You do not need to call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken2)` before calling `CreateProcessAsUser(hToken2, ...)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks. It's a different subject but I was curious about it. Is there an explanation when one needs to call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`? I've been always unclear about it.

Comment: You impersonate when you want to call an API that acts on behalf of the user currently associated with the calling thread, but your thread is associated with a different user than the one you want the API to see. APIs where you pass a user token to them, like `CreateProcessAsUser()`, do not have that requirement as the token has everything they need.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thank you. I appreciate your explanation. It makes sense now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: according to the MSDN documentation, you need to use impersonation with CreateProcessAsUser if you want the system to open the executable file in the target user's security context rather than that of the caller.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Um, OK: [CreateProcessAsUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Hmm. So I need that `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` call that I commented out?

Comment: Probably not, in this scenario - presumably you're in control of the executable in question, and I can't imagine any reason that you'd want to give it permissions that deny access to local system.  If anything, it would be the other way around: if you want for any reason to prevent unprivileged users from running your executable directly, assign permissions that *only* allow access to the Administrators well-known SID, and make sure you *don't* use impersonation when launching the process. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I have never seen that requirement before, but then I only use `CreateProcessAsUser()` from services running as LOCALSYSTEM so access was never a problem for me.

Comment: Found some additional info in the description for Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection) - it says: "Disabling file system redirection affects only operations made by the current thread. Some functions, such as CreateProcessAsUser, do their work on another thread, which is not affected by the state of file system redirection in the calling thread."  - my reading is it means it's actually useless to call ImpersonateLoggedOnUser when CreateProcessAsUser is utilized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. Here it is for whoever runs into it as well:

Add this after `DuplicateTokenEx` call:

```
HANDLE hToken2;
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hToken2);

//ONLY if requiring UIAccess!
DWORD dwUIAccess = 1;
::SetTokenInformation(hToken2, TokenUIAccess, &dwUIAccess, sizeof(dwUIAccess));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this! Saved me lots of pain.