# Get the list of Apps with corresponding images that are consuming CPU

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, wmi

I want to get the list of applications(preferably Metro or UWP) apps that are currently running in the system and consuming CPU&Memory. I need the application name as well as the image associated with the application as shown in the image below.
[image] As we can see in the image that Microsoft Edge is being displayed with its icon.

I have a piece of code that helps me in getting the CPU consumption details.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

I want to have image icon as well as the name of preferably UWP /Store apps.

Comment: why did you vote it to be closed? I need help !

Comment: This is essentially the same [as your prior closed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474697/getting-the-cpu-memory-storage-usage-for-modern-apps-using-wpf-app). Your code snippet doesn't address _"getting the CPU consumption details"_ anyway. Not to mention **there is no question actually being asked**

Comment: apart from closing this , you can help or guide me ? atleast i am trying to do anything? any clues or anything shall be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the icon of the running process, then you can get it like this

```
Icon icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(theprocess.MainModule.FileName);
```

Then you can convert it to `Bitmap` like this,

```
var iconImage = icon.ToBitmap();
```

Namespace : `System.Drawing;`

Hope this helps.

Comment: any namespace to include for this ? what i want to do is to extract a list of runing process with their names and the app icon associated with that

Comment: Add this code inside your foreach loop. `theprocess` is your foreach iteration variable.

Comment: i made a console application and run VS as Admin. I am getting Win32Exception - An unhandled exception of type System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception occured in System.Dll .. Access is denied

Comment: @Apoorv There are plenty of reasons why you get an `Acess is denied` exception. accessing a x64 process from a 32bit process, trying to access a `System` process etc. Please see this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/q/3399819/5077042

Comment: I was going through many. some say the compilation should be AnyCPU ..and its the same for me ! let me check and get back to you

Comment: something or the other is missing..this time its unable to resolve ProcessAccessFlags

Comment: Is basically this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462270/get-file-icon-used-by-shell