# List all the process of 64bit windows in vb.net with idle time

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to list running processes using VS2015 Community but it gives win32 exception any clue what is wrong here ?
my objective is to detect and report the idle threads launched by 3rdparty application names of the sub-processes are different !

```
     imports System
     imports system.diagnostics
     imports system.componentmodel

     Try

            Dim ps() As Process
            ps = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
            For Each mp As Process In ps
                Debug.WriteLine(mp.MainModule.ToString)
                Dim li As New ListViewItem
                li = Me.ListView1.Items.Add("TEST")
                li.EnsureVisible()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
```

**error**

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (iusb3mon.exe)
System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule (NOTEPAD.EXE)
Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll
Access is denied
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied while getting process path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399819/access-denied-while-getting-process-path)

Comment: Try the link http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/how-to-get-elevated-process-path-in-net/ it may help you